# Python regular expressions 0 or more words from set

Tags: python, regex

I have a big block of text within which I am trying to look for a phrase. The phrase can be structured in a number of different ways.

1. First I want to look for a word from a set of words, let's call it
   set 1.
2. After that there must be a space or comma (or maybe something
   else that separates words)
3. Then there may be 0 or more words from set 2
4. Again followed by the word separation characters as in point 2 above
5. finally there should be a word from set 3

Ideally all of these should be in the same sentence.

set 1 = `(Potential|Ability|Possibility|need|requires|needs|plenty|for|Needing|Requiring)`

set 2 = `(for|to|of|full|a|be|complete|Internal)`

set 3 = `(renovate|improve|modernise|modernize|update|renovating|improving|modernising|modernizing|updating|potential|project|renovation)`

So I have this regex expression

```
(Potential|Ability|Possibility|need|requires|needs|plenty|for|Needing|Requiring)[ ,]*(for|to|of|full|a|be|complete|Internal)[ ,]*(renovate|improve|modernise|modernize|update|renovating|improving|modernising|modernizing|updating|potential|project|renovation)
```

Now this will match a phrase where there is 0 or 1 words from set 2 but not if there are multiples. e.g "provides a wonderful opportunity for someone to add their own stamp as the property needs complete renovation throughout."

as soon as I add in 'a' before 'complete' it fails. The same as if I add another 'complete'.

How do I specify to look for 0 or multiple words from a set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set 1: Matches any of the words in set 1 with 1 separator.

```
(Potential|Ability|Possibility|need|requires|needs|plenty|for|Needing|Requiring)[ ,]
```

Set 2: Matches any of the words in set 2 with 1 separator, 0 or more times.

```
((for|to|of|full|a|be|complete|Internal)[ ,])*
```

Set 3: Matches any of the words in set 3

```
(renovate|improve|modernise|modernize|update|renovating|improving|modernising|modernizing|updating|potential|project|renovation)
```

Full:

```
(Potential|Ability|Possibility|need|requires|needs|plenty|for|Needing|Requiring)[ ,]((for|to|of|full|a|be|complete|Internal)[ ,])*(renovate|improve|modernise|modernize|update|renovating|improving|modernising|modernizing|updating|potential|project|renovation)
```

Comment: `{1}` is useless.

Comment: I ran this in an online regex tester which came out find, but I've just tried to run it in a python script with the following 
'import re

text = "potential to modernise"
regex = re.match("((Potential|Ability|Possibility|need|requires|needs|plenty|for|Needing|Requiring)[ ,]((for|to|of|full|a|be|complete|Internal)[ ,])*(renovate|improve|modernise|modernize|update|renovating|improving|modernising|modernizing|updating|potential|project|renovation))", text)
match = regex.groups()
print(match)
'
and I get the error ......

Comment: .....
'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Charlie/Documents/python/regex_potential.py", line 5, in <module>
    match = regex.groups()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups' '

Comment: Case sensitivity... oops

Answer (score 2):

Long alternatives in regular expressions [can be quite slow](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/11/flashtext-a-library-faster-than-regular-expressions/). I'd suggest to take another approach. First segment the text (split to words) and the iterate over the array of words checking if subsequent sets of 3 words fulfil your requirements

Something like that (rather pseudocode than a real python):

```
def check(text):
  words = segment(text)
  for i in range(0, len(text)-2):
      check_word1(text[i]) and check_word1(text[i+1]) and check_word3(text[i+2])
```

Comment: `for i in range(0, len(text)-2):` then, since you're doing `i+2`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this regex:

```
(Potential|Ability|Possibility|need|requires|needs|plenty|for|Needing|Requiring)[ ,](for|to|of|full|a|be|complete|Internal)*[ ,](renovate|improve|modernise|modernize|update|renovating|improving|modernising|modernizing|updating|potential|project|renovation)
```

Because you have one word from first set. After that you have one space or comma.
Near you have 0 or more word from set 2. Then an other space or comma and finally one word from the last set.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you didn't know, you can use sites like https://regex101.com/ to test your regular expressions, and see why it works/it doesn't.

In this case, you need the ["zero or more" (`*`) operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) on your second group. The result would be:

```
(Potential|Ability|Possibility|need|requires|needs|plenty|for|Needing|Requiring)[ ,]*(for|to|of|full|a|be|complete|Internal)*[ ,]*(renovate|improve|modernise|modernize|update|renovating|improving|modernising|modernizing|updating|potential|project|renovation)
```

However, considering you probably want the words to be separated, just include the space on the operator (you can use a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) for that), resulting on:

```
(Potential|Ability|Possibility|need|requires|needs|plenty|for|Needing|Requiring)[ ,]*(?:(for|to|of|full|a|be|complete|Internal)[ ,]*)*(renovate|improve|modernise|modernize|update|renovating|improving|modernising|modernizing|updating|potential|project|renovation)
```

Comment: This will match `Potential,,,,fortooffullabecompleteInternal,  ,,,  , fortooffullabecompleteInternalfortooffullabecompleteInternalfortooffullabecompleteInternalrenovate`

Comment: I know, but since that's what he has on his regex I decided to modify it as little as possible (just in case he wants that behaviour for some reason)